# Multiple Select Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller, model

Is there a way to select multiple properties using the `.Select()` query?

Something like this

`model.Owners = eventResponse.Records.Select(x => x.Owner.Name && x.Subject).ToList();`

Now I know that syntax doesn't work and it's pseudo-code, but is there a way to do something that produces the same result?

Comment: Are you using this internally somewhere or as something like a return value?

Comment: returning a value. I am setting this equal to another model property, thats the issue

Comment: And I also need to loop over them in the view for a foreach, which is another task because it relys on the formatting of this...

Comment: Can you add the code for the source model and the destination model?

Answer (score 4):

You should use anonymous type:

```
model.Owners = eventResponse.Records.Select(x => new {Name = x.Owner.Name, Subject = x.Subject)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an anonymous type or a tuple:

```
eventResponse.Records.Select(x => new { Name = x.Owner.Name, Subject = x.Subject }).ToList();
```

Or...

```
eventResponse.Records.Select(x => (Name: x.Owner.Name, Subject: x.Subject)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a tuple like:

```
model.Owners = eventResponse.Records.Select(x => (x.Owner.Name, x.Subject)).ToList();
```

Comment: This is how I would do it, unless this value is going to be returned from the method. If thats the case I would recommend creating a new model to represent this instead.

Comment: You're right, but for example for private methods I'd also consider named tuples a good candidate.

Comment: Fair point, I should've clarified if it was returning these values and was publicly accessible. Named tuples would work well for something that was private.

Comment: Yea, I will be setting these values equal to another model property. These are all great suggestions, but I keep running into conversion errors. I can't convert type blah blah to type blah blah.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If it is connected via foreign key, then you should need to use .include extension. It's working for sure, especially for pseudo-code.

```
model.Owners = eventResponse.Records.include("Owner").Select(x => x.Owner.Name && x.Subject).ToList();
```